# How can I implement auto suggestion on search field vue js without vue router?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router, vuex

My view like this :

```
<div id="app">
    <h1>Simple typeahead example</h1>
    <input placeholder="Search US states" @input="input" v-model="typeahead" />
    <ul v-if="!selected && typeahead">
      <li v-for="state in states | filterBy typeahead" @click="select(state)">{{ state }}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

My vue component like this :

```
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        selected: null,
        typeahead: null,
      states: ['Alabama', 'Alaska', 'Arizona', 'Arkansas', 'California',
  'Colorado', 'Connecticut', 'Delaware', 'Florida', 'Georgia', 'Hawaii',
  'New Jersey', 'New Mexico', 'New York', 'North Carolina', 'North Dakota',
  'Ohio', 'Oklahoma', 'Oregon', 'Pennsylvania', 'Rhode Island',
  'Idaho', 'Illinois', 'Indiana', 'Iowa', 'Kansas', 'Kentucky', 'Louisiana',
  'Maine', 'Maryland', 'Massachusetts', 'Michigan', 'Minnesota',
  'Mississippi', 'Missouri', 'Montana', 'Nebraska', 'Nevada', 'New Hampshire',
  'South Carolina', 'South Dakota', 'Tennessee', 'Texas', 'Utah', 'Vermont',
  'Virginia', 'Washington', 'West Virginia', 'Wisconsin', 'Wyoming']
    },

    methods: {
        select: function(state){
        this.typeahead = state
        this.selected = state
      },

      input: function(){
        this.selected = null
      }
    }
});
```

Demo and full code like this : http://jsfiddle.net/oscar11/tm8k8907/10/

The code above works. But it use vue router

I do not want to use vue router

Is there any other way without using vue router?

Comment: there is not a single line dealing with vue-router? Or do you mean the pipe ( | )?

Comment: If the pipe is bothering you, you can also use v-if="checkMyLi(state)".

Comment: @Thomas Kleßen, Seems there is not a single line dealing with vue-router. My jsfiddle use vue js version 1.0.8.  I try use vue.js version 2.1.6 like this : http://jsfiddle.net/tm8k8907/12/. There exist error. How can I solve the error? This seems to be what I mean

Comment: @user1497119, I'm still confused. Try to answer this question with jsfiddle

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

html:

```
<li v-for="state in states" v-if="filterBySelect(state)" @click="select(state)">{{ state }}</li>
```

Method:

```
filterBySelect (value) {
    if (!this.typeahead || this.typeahead.length === 0) return true
    return value.toLowerCase().split(this.typeahead.toLowerCase()).length > 1
  }
```