# How to pass mock data to the search bar in Vuejs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I want to pass some mock data to the search bar, so when user type any character in the search bar, he should have some suggestions accordingly. As of now i have created search bar with some closing functionality. But need to know how to pass some data to the search bar

```js
import Vue from 'vue';

export default {
    name: 'searchBar',
    data() {
        return {
            open: false,
            current: 0,
            value: '',
            isSearchText: false
    }
    },

    props: {
        suggestions: {
            type: Array,
            required: true
        },

        selection: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
            twoWay: true
        }
    },
    watch: {
        
    },
    

    computed: {
        matches() {
            /*if(this.suggestions && this.suggestions.length > 0) {
            return this.suggestions.filter((str) => {
                return str.indexOf(this.selection) >= 0;
            });
        }*/
        },

        openSuggestion() {
            /*return this.selection !== "" &&
                   this.matches.length != 0 &&
                   this.open === true;*/
        }

    },

    methods: {
        enter() {
            this.selection = this.matches[this.current];
            this.open = false;
        },

        up() {
            if(this.current > 0)
                this.current--;
        },

        down() {
            if(this.current < this.matches.length - 1)
                this.current++;
        } ,

        isActive(index) {
            return index === this.current;
        },

        change() {
            if (this.open == false) {
                this.open = true;
                this.current = 0;
            }
            
            
            if(this.search == "") {
                this.isSearchText = false;
            } else {
                this.isSearchText = true;
            }
            
        },

        suggestionClick(index) {
            this.selection = this.matches[index];
            this.open = false;
        },

        clearSearch(i) {
            if(this.search != "" ){
                this.search = "";
                document.getElementById("SearchText").value = "";
                this.isSearchText = false;
            }
            
        }
    }
  };
```

```html
<template>
<div>
<div class="input-group">
<div v-bind:class="{'open':openSuggestion}" class="search-bar">
    <input class="form-control bg-light-blue" id="SearchText"  type="text" v-model="search"
        @keydown.enter = 'enter'
        @keydown.down = 'down'
        @keydown.up = 'up'
        @input = 'change'
    />
    <span v-if="isSearchText" class="close-icon" @click="clearSearch"></span>
    <!--<i class="fa fa-times-circle-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>-->
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary search-icon">
        <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
    </button>
    </div>

    <ul v-if="matches && matches.length > 0" class="dropdown-menu" style="width:100%">
        <li v-for="suggestion in matches" :key="suggestion"
            v-bind:class="{'active': isActive($index)}"
            @click="suggestionClick($index)"
        >
            <a href="#">{{ suggestion }}</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
</template>
```

I want to pass some mock data to the search bar, so when user type any character in the search bar, he should have some suggestions accordingly. As of now i have created search bar with some closing functionality. But need to know how to pass some data to the search bar

Comment: Have you tried some other answers from previous questions? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47846352/how-can-i-implement-auto-suggestion-on-search-field-vue-js-without-vue-router

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59086809/autocomplete-search-with-key-down-and-up-in-vuejs